# using XmlPullParser in annotation on Android

Tags: java, android, gradle, annotations, dependencies

I'm trying to write an annotation processor that parses XML files and generates classes from them.  The annotation is going to be used in an Android app, but my understanding is the annotation processor itself runs in the Java environment of the compiler.  As such, I don't have access to the built-in Android XmlPullParser, so I've listed `org.ogce:xpp3:1.1.6` as a dependency in my annotation processor's gradle file.  My annotation processor is a separate module from the app (a Java Library module), in Android Studio.  My app has a depends on this module.

This mostly works!  My annotation processor runs and can successfully parse the XML.  Unfortunately, I get this error when generating the APK for my android app:

```
trouble processing "javax/xml/namespace/QName.class":
Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
when not building a core library.
This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
going on.
However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
It is also often of questionable legality.
If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.
If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
building an application, then be forewarned that your application
will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
system. You will be to blame for this problem.
If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.
1 error; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_66.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I think, despite the unexpected class name in the error, that it doesn't like that I've included XmlPullParser in my app because it is provided by the system.  So I did this in my app's gradle file to exclude it from the app's APK:

```
compile(project(':annotation-module')) {
    exclude module: 'xpp3' // Android provides the XmlPull API so we can't include it
}
```

This results in a compile time exception from Javac when processing the annotation:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserException
```

I'm at a loss for how to resolve this.  Is there no way I can include XPP in the Jar for my annotation processor but exclude it from the final APK?  Is there some other approach I'm missing?  I can't be the first person to try to parse XML in an annotation processor.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to 'shadow' the XPP jar. Basically, you need to download the aar, extract out the jar file, then repackage it in a different namespace (with e.g. the [shadow gradle plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow)) and change your imports so they refer to the shadowed jar.

Comment: I was thinking that might be the only way.  That's a lot of work.  I really don't want any of the annotation-related code in my APK, I want it to be entirely compile-time.  If only there was a way to make a compiler plugin.  I think I'm going to make a standalone app and use it as a custom pre-build step.